# "Geheimnisvoll" Nomen / noun

Tags: word-choice, etymology, noun

Is there a noun for *geheimnisvoll*, for example "Geheimnisvollheit" or "Geheimniskeit" or "Geheimnisheit".

I don't mean "Geheimnis".

Especially in the sentence "Land der Geheimnis....." (not "Geheimnisse")

Comment: Could you add more context, especially why 'Land voller Geheimnisse' does not qualify, and what kind of geheimnisvolle things are going on there: people's behaviour, archeological mysteries, ...

Comment: A single word for this is not existing, if you are looking for a one-to-one translation of a word in your mother tongue. Otherwise provide some more information about the contect of the use.

Comment: Es müsste *Geheimnisfülle* sein, aber das Wort hat es nicht in ein mir bekanntes Wörterbuch geschafft. Hier trotzdem ein Beleg: https://www.universal-music.de/goetz-alsmann/news/biografie-mein-geheimnis-track-by-track-doc-221065

Comment: Was spricht gegen _Geheimnisvollheit_? Andere Worte bilden wir auch nach diesem Schema, und es googlet gar nicht schlecht ...

Comment: I am surprised on the VtC, this is typical question what only a native speaker can answer and probably totally unreachable on Google.

Comment: @ingmar es klingt falsch

Comment: @peterh edit it

Answer (score 4):

> Mysterium

lt. Online-Duden: geheimnisvolles, mit dem Verstand nicht ergründbares Geschehen; unergründliches Geheimnis besonders religiöser Art

würde dann ergeben

> Land der Mysterien

was zwar schon etwas abgedroschen ist, aber trotzdem noch irgendwie ganz nett klingt. Natürlich nur meiner Meinung nach.

Comment: Es wäre vielleicht passender, auf eine englische Frage, auch auf Englisch zu antworten.

Answer (score 3):

There is Geheimniskrämerei, which means 'obsessive keeping of secrets', but geheimnisvoll is tied to 'voller Geheimnisse'(full of secrets', so 'Land der Geheimniskrämerei' doesn't hit the mark. 
'Land der Mystik' comes close, as does 'Land der Rätselhaftigkeit' -although the latter sounds weird.
'Land der Mysterien' would just replace Geheimnisse.

Comment: +1 for *Land voller Geheimnisse* - that's what came to my mind first

Answer (score 3):

A possibility would be to turn the adjective »geheim« or »geheimnisvoll« into a noun (*Substantivierung*):

> - Land des Geheimen
> - Land des Geheimnisvollen (*more natural:* Geheimnisvolles Land)

»Das Geheime« means all that is secret.

Or, if it fits your context:

> Land der Geheimhaltung

Comment: Land des Geheimen works great, i think! Land der Geheimhaltung is probably not what OP is looking for, as it is very strongly to the side of 'institutional keeping of secrets, Offical Secrets Act'

Comment: Also ist Geheimnisvollen in dem Kontext ein Nomen?

Comment: @Squareoot: Ja, das ist eine Substantivierung des Adjektivs _»geheimnisvoll«_.